# laravel only takes the first character in the string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 4.2 and am attempting to pull a string from the a database column named $meta_title and save that string as the meta tag in the view. It should work like this:

```
$meta_title = 'Star Wars is Better than Star Trek';
```

`$meta_title` is pulled from the database in the controller and sent to the view via an array

```
<meta property="og:title" content= {{ $meta_title }}  {{ '>' }} 
<meta property="og:title" content="Star Wars is Better than Star Trek">
```

but instead it does this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Star" wars="" is="" better="" than="" star="" trek="">
```

How can I fix the code so that the the meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Star Wars is Better than Star Trek">
```

after the string is pulled from the database?

Comment: Just want to add that you have a major error in your code - star wars is NOT better than star trek.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put `{{ $meta_title }}` inside `double quote`

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $meta_title }}">
```

From your code, after it renders to html it will look like this

```
<meta property="og:title" content= Star Wars is Better than Star Trek  >
```

That is why you got a weird output.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you do this?

```
<meta property="og:title" content= "{{ $meta_title }}" >
```